# How to generate color palette based on given image?

Tags: graphics

I would like to generate color palette based on the given image containig max. 10 colors.  Assume that, the given picture is bot bigger then 800x600 px. I've tried the next algorithm:

```
Generate 500 random X, Y values.
Check the colors' R,G,B values at the (X,Y) position, put colors into an array.
Find similar colors to each color, count how many similar colors have found. (Similar means: +- 10 difference in R, G, B)
Display colors which have the most similar colors.
```

The result is not what I expect. Any idea how to get the appropriate colors?

[An example, I want something like this](http://www.palettefx.com/)

Comment: Look up "Color quantization" using your favourite web search tool. It's an ancient and well-researched question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want Median Cut or K-means.

With median cut, you'll generate a point cloud of color samples from your source image. Divide the pointcloud in half at its median across the axis with maximum variance, creating two sub-pointclouds. Recursively divide these until you have the desired number of leaf nodes. You can then generate a palette by averaging the color samples in each leaf node.

With K-means, you select `k` random color samples from your image. These will be the first color samples in `k` buckets. Then, for each pixel, add its color value to the bucket whose average color is closest to that of the pixel in question-- you may use euclidean distance to determine "closeness". After all pixels have been sampled, the average colors of the `k` buckets is your palette.

You will get better results if you first convert your color samples to CIE lab color space, where euclidean distance is a better measure of perceptual distance.